# Zero-length packets for USB control transfers

Tags: controls, usb, stm32, transfer, libusb

In the context of a DFU driver, I'm trying to respond with a packet of length zero (not ZLP as in multiples of max size, just zero bytes) to a USB control in transfer. However, the host returns with a timeout condition. I tried both, the dfu-util tool and the corresponding protocol, as well as a minimal working example with pyusb just issuing a control in transfer of some length and the device returning no data.

My key question is: Do I achieve this by responding with a NAK or should I set the endpoint valid but without any data? The specs are rather vague about this, imo.

Here are some technical details since I'm not sure where the problem is:

- Host: Linux Kernel 5.16.10, dfu-util and pyusb (presumably) both using libusb 0.1.12
- Device: STM32L1 with ChibiOS 21.11.1 USB stack (sends NAK in the above situation, I also tried to modify it to send a zero-length packet without success)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are programming the firmware of a device, and you want your device to give a response that is 0 bytes long when the host starts a control read transfer.

You can't simply send a NAK token: that is what the device does when the data isn't ready yet, and it causes the host to try again later to read the data.

Instead, you must actually send a 0-length IN packet to the host.  When the host receives this packet, it sees that the packet is shorter than the maximum packet size, so it knows the data phase of the control transfer is done, and it moves on to the status stage.